# install Laravel on share folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

We have a appserver3 over LAN, means there is folder in remote server and I just map that folder in my my compurt and suppose it got the drive letter G. now when I excute the following

```
php artisan migrate --package=cartalyst/sentry
```

but it try to install db in my localhost. But I want to db operation in appserver3. please help me

Comment: By mapping the drive you're not using the server as anything but a storage device for your computer. To install anything on the server you will want SSH access to it and do it from the shell/command line of the server.

Comment: @David Barker actually I am new in laravel can you please give me any reference site so that I can learn it quickly

Comment: Google(search) is your friend. Try searching for "How do I login into my server with SSH"

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have the web server and database up on your appserver3. You could add a new set of config files for your "appserver3" machine, and make sure the db host points to the appserver3's ip address. Something like this:

app/config/appserver3/database.php:

```
'connections' => array(
    ...
    'host' => 'your appserver3 ip address',
    ...
)
```

Then you can run artisan command and specify the environment:

```
php artisan migrate --package=cartalyst/sentry --env=appserver3
```